# UITableViewCells stop displaying correctly after X cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Swift 4 + Xcode 9.

I have been working on this problem for weeks, trying to solve it myself.  I would appreciate any help that anyone could provide.  I'm not posting any code in my initial question because it's proprietary.  I will be happy to provide pieces of it if it's required to help solve my problem.

I have a `UITableView` with a custom cell, which contains a very complex layout of subviews, some of which are hidden or shown (using `1000-priority` `height=0` constraints which are added and removed during `cellForRowAt`) depending on the data.  There is also an `ImageView` which should always be full width, and should change height to match the image, which is loaded via `Kingfisher.shared.retrieveImage()`.  Once I have the image, I update the `aspectRatio` constraint on the image for that cell, and the cells display.  This works perfectly for the first 15-20 cells, but as I scroll through more rows, it simply stops functioning.  The images are small and centered, certain data fields are not updated, etc.  If I keep scrolling, sometimes a cell will behave correctly here and there, but nearly all do not.

Now for the interesting part:  If I scroll BACK UP, every single cell reformats itself automatically to look as it should, and after that, every cell is perfect.  The code obviously works - and I feel like this may be a bug in the platform, but before I assume that, I wanted to see if anyone else had run into something like this.

Again, thank you very much for any help you can provide - I'm very anxious to solve this.

**UPDATE: To answer a couple of the questions, here is a snippet of code that is part of the custom cell class.  This is how I set the cell's image (which includes updating the aspect ratio constraint), and how I reset the cell for re-use.**

```
internal var aspectConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint? {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != nil {
            imageView.removeConstraint(oldValue!)
        }
        if aspectConstraint != nil {
            imageView.addConstraint(aspectConstraint!)
        }
    }
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    aspectConstraint = nil
    imageView.image = nil
    for view in subviews {
        for c in view.constraints {
            if c.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height && c.constant == 0 {
                view.removeConstraint(c)
            }
        }
    }
}

func setCustomImage(image : UIImage) {
    let aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height
    let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, multiplier: aspect, constant: 0.0)
    constraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(999)
    aspectConstraint = constraint
    imageView.image = image
}
```

Comment: can you please share the pic @joel

Comment: It sounds like you might have extra constraints because of cell reuse.  What are you doing to ensure that any constraints that have been added are removed when a cell is reused?  How are you *updating* the aspect ratio constraint?

Comment: Adding to what @vacawama said: this sounds very much like a problem with cell reuse. The culprit is likely to be in your `prepareForReuse` method. This should reset every cell that's reused to a pristine state.

Comment: The other thing that you **must** do if you have variable height cells is implement `heightForRowAt:` and/or `estimatedHeightForRowAt:` otherwise the tableview won’t be able to calculate the scrollview offsets properly and you get the problem you are describing.

Comment: I've added information to the question which hopefully will answer the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes to this question, due to complete lack of resolution on this issue, I have concluded that UIKit is unsuitable for my purposes.  I went with [Texture](http://texturegroup.org) (formerly AsyncDisplayKit), and my progress has resumed.